# Rename multiple files with 2 conditions/replacements in one line?

Tags: files, rename, replace

I'm trying to rename a few images:

```
IMG_1.JPG
IMG_2.JPG
IMG_3.JPG
```

I want to replace `IMG` with `img` and `.JPG` with `.jpg` - I know how to do the second part:

```
$ rename 's/\.JPG$/\.jpg/' *.JPG
```

My problem is that I can't seem to `mv` `IMG_.JPG` to `img_.jpg` - I know you can pass multiple patterns to `rename`, but I can't seem to use the existing filename with an amended lowercase value.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you need to be using the perl rename command.  On my CentOS box, it's called 'prename'.

```
$ ls
IMG_1.JPG  IMG_2.JPG  IMG_3.JPG
$ prename 's/^IMG/img/;s/\.JPG$/\.jpg/' *JPG
$ ls
img_1.jpg  img_2.jpg  img_3.jpg
$

$ prename -h
Usage: prename [OPTION]... PERLEXPR FILE...
Rename FILE(s) using PERLEXPR on each filename.

  -b, --backup                  make backup before removal
  -B, --prefix=SUFFIX           set backup filename prefix
  -f, --force                   remove existing destinations, never prompt
  -i, --interactive             prompt before overwrite
  -l, --link-only               link file instead of reame
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run   don't rename, implies --verbose
  -v, --verbose                 explain what is being done
  -V, --version-control=METHOD  override the usual version control
  -Y, --basename-prefix=PREFIX  set backup filename basename prefix
  -z, -S, --suffix=SUFFIX       set backup filename suffix
      --help                    display this help and exit
      --version                 output version information and exit

The backup suffix is ~, unless set with SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.  The
version control may be set with VERSION_CONTROL, values are:

  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups

Report bugs to pederst@cpan.org
$
```

If you want to use the dumb `rename` command from `util-linux` (sometimes called `rename.ul`), perhaps needs doing in two steps, e.g.

```
$ ls
IMG_1.JPG  IMG_2.JPG  IMG_3.JPG
$ rename IMG img *JPG
$ rename JPG jpg *JPG
$ ls
img_1.jpg  img_2.jpg  img_3.jpg
$
```

Comment: Note that the `perl` `rename` predates the dumb `rename` found in util-linux that you call _plain old `rename`_. It even predates Linux.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what do you mean by "It even predates Linux". I imagine it is some sort of methaphore/euphemism, but I don't get it.

Comment: @onlycparra, first release of Linux is from 1991. The `rename` example script was added to `perl` in 3.0 in 1990, which is what I meant by "it predates Linux".

Comment: my brain, which is still learning English took me the wrong way one more time. Somehow I related "predates" with "predator"... On the plus side, new word + potential jokes for the future.

Answer (score 6):

To answer you question in the generic,

> rename multiple files with 2 conditions/replacements in one line?

you would typically use *capture groups*, referring to them in the replacement expression using their corresponding *backreferences*. For example

```
$ rename -n 's/^(.*)_(.*)\.JPG$/\L$1_$2.jpg/' *.JPG
rename(IMG_2.JPG, img_2.jpg)
rename(IMG_3.JPG, img_3.jpg)
```

However, in this particular case, it would be simpler to just apply the lowercase modifier `\L` to the whole name:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*/\L$&/' *.JPG
rename(IMG_2.JPG, img_2.jpg)
rename(IMG_3.JPG, img_3.jpg)
```

Another alternative, using `mmv`

```
$ mmv -n '*.JPG' '#l1.jpg'
IMG_2.JPG -> img_2.jpg
IMG_3.JPG -> img_3.jpg
```

(remove the `-n` to actually perform the rename).

Comment: Or `zmv`'s: `zmv '*.JPG' '${(L)f}'`

Comment: A simpler version of `rename 's/.*/\L$&/' *.JPG` would be `rename '$_ = lc' *.JPG`

Answer (score 2):

Using `mv`:

sh compatible:

```
for file in *.JPG; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"; done
```

bash (Thanks steeldriver):

```
for file in *.JPG; do mv "$file" "${file,,}"; done
```

This will loop through all `.JPG` files in the current directory and rename them to the same name with all uppercase characters converted to lowercase characters.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way and based on [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) that does not cover a [*regular expression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
rename 'IMG' 'img' * ; rename 'JPG' 'jpg' *
```

Comment: IMHO, a simple answer like this achieves what the heavy hitting occasionally fails to. No malice towards seasoned programmers, but since the question seems to be from a newbie, simplicity needs to be encouraged.